# How can I find out, that a Node or a ButtonBase is a Button?

Tags: java, if-statement, button, javafx, nodes

The title says it. How can I check that a `Node item` or a `ButtonBase Item` is a `Button`? Can I use the equals method?

```
public void initListener(ArrayList<TreeItem> treeBranches, ButtonBase item){

    if(item != null && **item.equals**....?)){ ... }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(item != null && item instanceof Button) { ... }
```

or simply, since `(null instanceof Button) == false`:

```
if(item instanceof Button) { ... }
```